# MySQL adds a question mark (?) to empty HTML Paragraph

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework

I have a table called `adbase` which has an HTML field called `DescriptionHtmlString`, this is the definition of the table:

```
CREATE TABLE `adbase` (
  AdBaseId bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  UserId bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  Title varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  DescriptionHtmlString varchar(14000) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  -- more columns
```

now I am entering the following HTML text into `DescriptionHtmlString`:

```
<div class="respect-p">
  <article>
    <ul>
      <li><p><b>Maintenance Manager role within an iconic, exciting and challenging business</b></p></li> 
      <li><p><b>Attractive remuneration package on offer</b></p></li>
    </ul>
    <p class="p1"></p>
    <!-- 
      more html text ...
    -->
```

The issue is once I write the above text to MySQL table, the empty paragraph: `<p class="p1"></p>` becomes: `<p class="p1">?</p>` in the DB.

I tried debugging the code to figure out where is the question mark added, this is the very last step before entity framework adds the html text into the DB, and the text still contains: `<p class="p1"></p>`

[image]

[image]

I have also captured the SQL statement that EF executes (from the Output window) and even then, there is no question mark in the paragraph:

[image]

But when I read the value written to DB, the question mark is added:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got an invisible character in that place. Your code shows ? as it is not configured to show the invisible character.

Comment: Thanks, any idea how to remove the invisible character?

Comment: Initially you should clean your input before the insert, if you do not want such characters. If you want to clear that from the the database, do simple update: "update adbase set DescriptionHtmlString = replace(DescriptionHtmlString, '​COPY_PASTE_THE_CHARACTER_HERE', '');". The character in question is Unicode ZERO WIDTH SPACE (U+200B).

Comment: Thanks, it was exactly as you said,  ZERO WIDTH SPACE character (which I had never heard of before)